# How to get selected value from table using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need one help.I need some selected value using check box select using Angular.js.I am explaining my code below.

```
    <tr dir-paginate="pro in listOfReview | itemsPerPage:5">
    <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="selected[pro.review_id]" ng-false-value="undefined"></td>
    <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
    <td>{{pro.Product_name}}</td>
    <td>{{pro.title}}</td>
    <td>{{pro.description}}</td>
    <td>{{pro.rating}}</td>
     <td ng-if="pro.status==0">Not Approved</td>
    <td ng-if="pro.status==1">Approved</td>
    <td ng-if="pro.status==1">
    <a ui-sref="review">
    <input type='button' class='btn btn-xs btn-red' value='Reject' ng-click="RejectStatus(pro.review_id,pro.status);" >  
    </a>
    </td>
    <td ng-if="pro.status==0">
    <a ui-sref="review">
    <input type='button' class='btn btn-xs btn-green' value='Approve' ng-click="ApproveStatus(pro.review_id,pro.status);" >  
    </a>
     </td>
    </tr>   
 <input type='button' class='btn btn-xs btn-green' value='Approve' ng-click="ApproveStatus();">
```

The controller side code is given below.

```
$scope.selected = {};
 $scope.ApproveStatus=function(){
         console.log('approve',$scope.selected);
}
```

right now i am getting the selected value like this `approve Object {4: true}` .Here i need to assign `pro.review_id` value to a key like(`review:id:4`) so that i can easily fetch those using loop.Here also my requirement is when at least one check box will select the Approve button  present at bottom will display to the user.Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

plunker link [Click here](http://plnkr.co/edit/RzPpikvDEjN1mpmyPsJ8?p=preview)

You can bind an extra property with check box like I did below.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>

    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">

      <table>
        <tr><td></td><td>Name</td><td>Type</td><td>Price</td></tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="p in prods">
          <td><input type='checkbox' value ="p.checked" ng-model="p.checked"></td>
          <td>{{p.name}}</td>
          <td>{{p.type}}</td>
          <td>{{p.price}}</td>
          <td>Delete</td>
          <td>Modify</td>
        </tr>

      </table>

      <input type="button" value="Approve" ng-click="ApproveStatus()" />
    </div>

  </body>
</html>


function Ctrl($scope) {


  $scope.prods = [
    {'id':'0', 'name' : 'Title1', 'type' : 'Zip code', 'price' : '11'},
    {'id':'1', 'name' : 'Title2', 'type' : 'MD', 'price' : '222'},
    {'id':'2', 'name' : 'Title3', 'type' : 'DMS', 'price' : '2222'}
];


  $scope.ApproveStatus = function(){
    console.log('value is:' + $scope.prods.length);
    for(var i =0; i < $scope.prods.length ;i++){
    if($scope.prods[i].checked){
         console.log($scope.prods[i].id)      
      }
    }

  };
}
```

Comment: in your case you are setting static data in controller side function and inside you are setting Boolean condition but can you edit my code using your way?

Comment: even if checked property does not exist in object , you still can use it in html. please have a look at updated code in plnker and above. let me know if you need help to understand it.

Comment: yes,its coming properly.Let me to implement those in my code.